# DLookUp select secondary email if primary is empty or null

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that is selecting emails based on companies that have expired insurances. Some companies have both a Business and personal emails whilst others have one or the other.
I am using the DLookUp function to select the email based on Suppliers meeting the filter criteria.
Is there a way for me to select the BusinessEmail but if they don't have one it selects the PersonalEmail instead?

Currently I have started with `=DLookUp("BusinessEmail","tblContacts","Supplier ID = " & [txtSupplierID]` and then went to use an IIf statement in it but I was lost as to how it would then select the other email or if it would work that way.

[contacts sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DP98.png)

Comment: Does each company have only one record in tblContacts? What table is form bound to? Why not include tblContacts in form RecordSource? Do you have a combobox for selecting supplier? Could include email as column of combobox and textbox expression can reference combobox column by its index. Either approach is usually preferable to DLookup which can slow performance of forms and queries.

Comment: They can have multiple contact records. Typically the office contact is the one that has the business email and any other contacts such as project managers have personal emails listed.

Comment: If there are multiple contact records with the same SupplierID, your DLookup doesn't have criteria to determine which one to pull value from. And if BusinessEmail and PersonalEmail are not in same record, this gets complicated. Edit question to show sample data as text tables.

Comment: sample data added.

Comment: @June7: Your deleted answer using _Nz_ will work with sample data.

Comment: @Gustav, maybe for this specific example but could not be relied on in all cases with only SupplierID as filter criteria. If there weren't any business email, which personal email should be retrieved? I think this calls for a VBA custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DLookup()` function returns null if the value was not found, so you can make use of the `Nz()` function to check for the personal email, if the business email is null.

Since we assign the return value to a string and strings cannot hold null values, we make use of the `Nz()` function again to return an empty string, if the personal email doesn't exists too (to avoid the error).

```
Dim criteria As String
criteria = "[Supplier ID] = " & [txtSupplierID]

Dim email As String
email = Nz(DLookup("BusinessEmail", "tblContacts", criteria), Nz(DLookup("PersonalEmail", "tblContacts", criteria), vbNullString))
```

**Edit:**

---

Adding a second rule to the `DLookup` to exclude null values, should work. See a helper function to get the email through an output parameter and report success/failure:

```
Private Function TryGetEmail(ByVal supplierId As Long, ByRef outEmail As String) As Boolean

    Dim retValue As Variant
    
    'try to get business
    retValue = DLookup("BusinessEmail", "tblContacts", "[Supplier ID] = " & supplierId & " AND BusinessEmail Is Not Null")
    If Not IsNull(retValue) Then
        outEmail = retValue
        TryGetEmail = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'try to get personal
    retValue = DLookup("PersonalEmail", "tblContacts", "[Supplier ID] = " & supplierId & " AND PersonalEmail Is Not Null")
    If Not IsNull(retValue) Then
        outEmail = retValue
        TryGetEmail = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'none found
    outEmail = vbNullString
    TryGetEmail = False
    
End Function
```

---

To call it:

```
Sub T()

    Dim supplierId As Long
    Dim email As String
    
    supplierId = 19
    
    If Not TryGetEmail(supplierId, email) Then
        MsgBox "No email found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'email now holds one of the two emails

End Sub
```

Comment: I think a VBA custom function is right track but what if DLookup hits record with no business email and disregards the others? And if there is no business email, which personal email should be pulled?

Comment: If there are no emails for suppliers that were selected in the filter how would I go about implementing some error handling or just a message display that lists the Suppliers that did not have an email pulled through? Also any email can be used from personal as all contacts are typically in a management position and can forward it onto the relevant people.

Comment: Adding a second rule to exclude null values should work. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the field "Supplier ID" to "SupplierID", it will make your development easier.

Here are some code using both Dlookup and IIf, putting the result in a textbox named txtEmail:

```
Private Sub getEmail()
    txtEmail = DLookup("Iif(Isnull(BusinessEmail),PersonalEmail,BusinessEmail)", "tblContacts", "SupplierID = " & txtSupplierID)
End Sub
```

or this:

```
Private Sub getEmail()
    Dim Email As Variant
    
    Email = DLookup("BusinessEmail", "tblContacts", "SupplierID = " & txtSupplierID)
    If IsNull(Email) Then Email = DLookup("PersonalEmail", "tblContacts", "SupplierID = " & txtSupplierID)
    
    txtEmail = Email
End Function
```

Comment: I think a VBA custom function is right track but what if DLookup hits record with no business email and disregards the others? And if there is no business email, which personal email should be pulled?